# Is it possible to achieve erlang formatting like this?

Tags: indentation, major-mode, erlang-mode

As I was going through [learnyousomeerlang](http://learnyousomeerlang.com/syntax-in-functions#what-the-if) I came across code formatted like so:

```
if X > Y -> a()
 ; true  -> b()
end
```

Presently As close as I can get is:

```
if X > Y ->
    a()
        ;
->
```

I am assuming this is due to the electric > and electric ;. In Erlang.el. I'm just wondering If anyone happens to know of a useful criteria for the electric-semicolon and such that would make this possible.

Answer (score 2):

It's not only about the electric semicolon; it's also the indentation functions themselves that indent the semicolon too far.  The indentation level is calculated in the function `erlang-calculate-stack-indent`.  It would be nice if this behaviour were configurable, a bit like how you can select different styles in `cc-mode`, but it currently isn't.

Comment: I'm not really that well versed with elisp and such, would something like this https://github.com/kwrooijen/indy be helpful?